# Attempting to assign a variable to an value causes "Cannot assign to operator" error

Tags: python, operator-keyword

```
    def main():
    bonus()
def bonus():
    #Dollars from sales are input, then time worked,
    #then the salary and possible bonus is added
    #to the calculated commission based on the earned commission rate
    monthlySales=int(input('How much money did your employee make in sales?',))
    if monthlySales<10000:
        commRate=0
    elif monthlySales>=10000 and monthlySales<100000:
        commRate=0.02
    elif monthlySales>=100001 and monthlySales<500000:
        commRate=0.15 and monthlyBonus=1000
    elif monthlySales>=500001 and monthlySales<1000000:
        commRate=0.28 and monthlyBonus=5000
    elif monthlySales>1000000:
        commRate=0.35 and monthlyBonus=100000
    yearsWorked=int(input('How many years has your employee worked here? Round down to the nearest year.',))
    if yearsWorked>=5 and monthlySales>=100000:
        extraBonus+1000
    elif yearsWorked<1:
        monthsWorked=int(input('How many full months has your employee worked here?',))
        if monthsWorked<3:
            print('Your employee has not worked here long enough to qualify for a bonus.')            
main()
```

What I'm trying to do is make a program on which predetermined commission rates are based on how much in sales an employee made are input into the program.

I'm getting a "Cannot assign to operator" error on

```
commRate=0.35 and monthlyBonus=100000
```

, which tells me that I'll get the same error on the rest of the variables that have been directly assigned numerical values amongst the `if` nesting.

What all am I doing wrong, here?

Comment: sepearate into two lines droping `and`or use semicolon `;`

Comment: Use tuple assignment `a, b = 1, 2` results in `a == 1` and `b == 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elif monthlySales>=100001 and monthlySales<500000:
    commRate=0.35 ; monthlyBonus=100000
```

or

```
elif monthlySales>=100001 and monthlySales<500000:
    commRate=0.35
    monthlyBonus=100000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply, dropping and worked perfectly. I'll have to learn more about operators.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use `and` operator while you are assigning the values to variables. But you can use to  check if the conditions (all conditions) have been met of `elif` statement.Try the following:

```
elif monthlySales>=100001 and monthlySales<500000:
    commRate=0.15
    monthlyBonus=1000
elif monthlySales>=500001 and monthlySales<1000000:
    commRate=0.28
    monthlyBonus=5000
elif monthlySales>1000000:
    commRate=0.35
    monthlyBonus=100000
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, assignments can not occur inside expressions unlike in C, so that's the reason for the error.  It is to prevent accidental assignments when a comparison was intended.  Please read about it here in the last paragraph of sec 5.7:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess (hope :) that isn't the full listing of your `bonus()` function, since it doesn't actually return or print any of the data it calculates. But I've noticed a couple of things in that function that you need to deal with.

The line `extraBonus+1000` performs a calculation on an undefined variable (extraBonus), and then it doesn't store the result anywhere.

The top two conditions in your `if...elif` section don't set a value for `monthlyBonus`; you need to fix that before you use `monthlyBonus` later in the function.

Also, that `if...elif` section performs redundant tests, so it can be simplified:

```
monthlyBonus = 0
if monthlySales < 10000:
    commRate = 0
elif monthlySales < 100000:
    commRate = 0.02
elif monthlySales < 500000:
    commRate = 0.15; monthlyBonus = 1000
elif monthlySales < 1000000:
    commRate = 0.28; monthlyBonus = 5000
else:
    commRate = 0.35; monthlyBonus = 100000
```

We don't get to `elif monthlySales < 100000` unless the previous test failed, so we know that `monthlySales>=10000` is true and testing it again is redundant. Etc.